# using list.files(pattern =) to import files from a vector, R

Tags: r, vector

Using R, I'm trying to import a list of files into my environment in RStudio with help of a numerical vector that's updated by other functions in the script but the pattern argument specified in list.files() is partly ignored. I have

```
test_list <- list.files(
                    path='~/somepath/'
                    , pattern = paste0(threshold_list, "\\.csv$")
                    , recursive = TRUE
                    , full.names = TRUE)
```

where threshold_list is vector consisting of integers that refer to a specific csv file,

```
[1]   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9  10 ...
```

so, if I were to print "paste0(threshold_list, "\\.csv$")", I get the file names I want:

```
"\\1.csv$"   "\\2.csv$"   "\\3.csv$"   "\\4.csv$" ... "\\150.csv$"
```

But, if I pass this vector to the pattern argument in list.files() and then execute the script, I will get the files in intervals of 10 which is not what I need;

```
 [1] ".../somepath/001.csv"
 [2] ".../somepath/011.csv"
 [3] ".../somepath/021.csv"
 [4] ".../somepath/031.csv"
 ...
 [n] ".../somepath/141.csv"
```

If the first component in the vector is e.g. 34, the first file will be "034.csv", and the same pattern will occur. When list.files(pattern="*.csv") **all** files within the directory are imported into the environment so I'm assuming the issue is with my regular expression in the pattern argument. I want the list to include every file name that's specified by "paste0(threshold_list, "\\.csv$")", how can I achieve this?

**Edit 1:** file names were actually 001.csv, 002.csv etc, converting the vector so that that all of it's components are three digit numbers,

`sprintf("%03d", threshold_list)`

and applying the given answer below, achieves the solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you don't use wildcards in regexp patterns, you should use class enumerations in square brackets

```
test_list <- list.files(path='~/somepath/', pattern = sprintf('%s\\.csv$', paste(threshold_list, sep='', collapse='|')), recursive = TRUE, full.names = TRUE)
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer! However, I tried this just now and unfortunately it doesn't work :( it imports every .csv file from the directory into the environment in the same way that list.files(pattern="*.csv") does

Comment: @scooptywoopty i corrected the mistake - character classes ONLY match single characters; you just need to use the alternating operator `|`

Comment: Just realised that I've made a mistake. The files all have 3 digits, so it's actually .../001.csv, .../002.csv,... etc, and I wouldn't have been searching for the file's path in the directory (I would have been searching for an index number). But, now I know i can modify the list so that `pattern = sprintf('%s\\.csv$', paste(sprintf("%03d", threshold_list), sep='', collapse='|'))`. I'm so sorry for wasting your time!! I will mark your post as the answer (because it is!) and add an edit to the question to clarify. It's my first week learning, so I really appreciate your help! Thank you

Comment: @scooptywoopty not sure why it works, but the list of alternatives should be surrounded by round brackets - `'(%s)\\.csv$'`